# Custom Jumplist Behavior

Tags: cursor-movement, mark, jumplist, movement

I enjoy using `ctrl-i` and `ctrl-o` to quickly jump back large distances in a file. I would enjoy if this functionality could be extended to the in-line motions such as `f`, `F`, `w`, `b`, ...

I understand that this doesn't happen normally because these movements are not defined to be jumps and thus don't get added to the `jumplist`.

---

I had the idea that this could be done by measuring manhattan distance of how far the cursor has moved, and if that distance is greater than some configurable threshold, then the previous position is added to the `jumplist`. This would allow the user to determine how much jumping they want. [with this we might run into problems where we do an actual jump like `ctrl-u` and then we would get two identical jump positions stored in the `jumplist`]

Alternatively maybe we know a list of the in-line commands and would be able to run `m'` before any such one is run.

---

Before I try to implement any of that, I am wondering if anyone has created any configuration or logic that deals with this in a robust way, and if they have if they could share how to do that.

Comment: Just try something.